# I am trying to align the caption text better

Tags: graphics

I made the following boxplots:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [title = {Lengths of Amplification and Deletion Regions},ylabel = {$log_{10}(Length)$},
    boxplot/draw direction=y,
    xtick={1,2,3},
    xticklabels={Amplification, Amplification (no genes), Deletion}
    ]
    \addplot+[mark = *, mark options = {red},
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=2.217484,
      lower quartile=3.541535,
      median=3.944694,
      upper quartile=4.572695,
      upper whisker=5.826493
    }, color = red
    ] coordinates{(0,6.29165)(0,6.21436)};
    \addplot+[mark = *,mark options = {green},
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=3.378943,
      lower quartile=3.759290,
      median=3.974834,
      upper quartile=4.272700,
      upper whisker=4.699447
    }, color = gree
    ] coordinates{(0,2.874482)(0,2.564666)(0,5.819792)};
    \addplot+[mark = *,mark options = {blue},
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=4.691824,
      lower quartile=5.236792,
      median=5.533932,
      upper quartile=5.997152,
      upper whisker=7.125098
    }, color = blue
    ] coordinates{(0,7.309382)(0,7.535505)(0,7.171933)(0,7.388371)(0,7.361202)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

that gives:

[image]

How could I make the caption look like this:

```
 Amplification   Amplification   Deletion
                    (no genes)
```

and maybe smaller as to avoid any overlap?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `x tick label style={font=\footnotesize, text width=3cm, align=center}` to the axis options. It will reduce the font, and provide a maximum text width of 3cm, which is enough for `(genes)` to go to a new line.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [title = {Lengths of Amplification and Deletion Regions},ylabel = {$log_{10}(Length)$},
    boxplot/draw direction=y,
    xtick={1,2,3},
    xticklabels={Amplification, Amplification (no genes), Deletion},
    x tick label style={font=\footnotesize, text width=3cm, align=center},
    ]
    \addplot+[mark = *, mark options = {red},
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=2.217484,
      lower quartile=3.541535,
      median=3.944694,
      upper quartile=4.572695,
      upper whisker=5.826493
    }, color = red
    ] coordinates{(0,6.29165)(0,6.21436)};
    \addplot+[mark = *,mark options = {green},
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=3.378943,
      lower quartile=3.759290,
      median=3.974834,
      upper quartile=4.272700,
      upper whisker=4.699447
    }, color = green
    ] coordinates{(0,2.874482)(0,2.564666)(0,5.819792)};
    \addplot+[mark = *,mark options = {blue},
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=4.691824,
      lower quartile=5.236792,
      median=5.533932,
      upper quartile=5.997152,
      upper whisker=7.125098
    }, color = blue
    ] coordinates{(0,7.309382)(0,7.535505)(0,7.171933)(0,7.388371)(0,7.361202)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Johnathan You're welcome!